# Making independent class with functionality and make usage of it in InterfaceController class

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have tried to make a separate class for the location functionality (separate swift file in the Watchkit Exension folder) and I want to use the location instance of that class in the InterfaceController class to track the location of the user. But, xcode gets stuck and I also cannot deploy and test the application. I do not know what the reason is.

Here is the location code and the InterfaceController class:

The whole project is here: https://filebin.net/s40xlqzeukfwc39w

I hope you can help me out since I am still a beginner in terms of Swift and WatchKit. Thank you very much.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationOutside{

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

   init(){
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy =  kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.delegate = (self as! CLLocationManagerDelegate)
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLoc =  locations[0]
        let lat = currentLoc.coordinate.latitude
        let long = currentLoc.coordinate.longitude
        print(lat)
        print(long)

    }

    func locationManager(_manager: CLLocationManager,didFailWithError error: Error){
        if let locationErr = error as? CLError{
            switch locationErr{
            case CLError.locationUnknown:
                print("unknown location")
            case CLError.denied:
                print("denied")
            default:
                print("another type of location error")
            }
        }else{
                print("other error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
}
```

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import HealthKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreMotion



let hrType:HKQuantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!

// Date will be constructed in database --> server side


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController,AVAudioRecorderDelegate{

    var saveUrl: URL?
    var outDoorLocation = LocationOutside.init()

    // to conduct permission to retrieve location data
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    // Outlets for testing
    @IBOutlet weak var button: WKInterfaceButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var furtherSigLabels: WKInterfaceLabel!
    var recordingSession : AVAudioSession!
    var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!
    var settings = [String : Any]()

    // distinguish start recording heartbeat
    var isRecording = false

    //For workout session
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    var session: HKWorkoutSession?
    var currentQuery: HKQuery?
    var filename: String?
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    var gravityStr = ""
    var userAccelerStr = ""
    var rotationRateStr = ""
    var attitudeStr = ""
    var movement = ""

    var manualLat: Double = 0.0
    var manualLong: Double = 0.0
    var heartRateVal: Double = 0.0
    var prev_grav_z: Double = 0.0
    var prev_acc_z: Double = 0.0
    var grav_x:Double = 0.0
    var grav_y:Double = 0.0
    var grav_z:Double = 0.0
    var acc_x:Double = 0.0
    var acc_y:Double = 0.0
    var acc_z:Double = 0.0

    var sendOrNot:Bool = false

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        /**
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        */

        // managing authorization
        let healthService:HealthDataService = HealthDataService()
        healthService.authorizeHealthKitAccess { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("HealthKit authorization received.")
            } else {
                print("HealthKit authorization denied!")
                if error != nil {
                    print("\(String(describing: error))")
                }
            }
        }

        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5
    }

    /**
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLoc =  locations[0]
        let lat = currentLoc.coordinate.latitude
        let long = currentLoc.coordinate.longitude

        manualLat = lat
        manualLong = long

        /**
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://147.46.242.219/addgps.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(lat)&b=\(long)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }

        task.resume()

        */
    }

 */
    /**
    func locationManager(_: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        let err = CLError.Code(rawValue: (error as NSError).code)!
        switch err {
        case .locationUnknown:
            break
        default:
            print(err)
        }
    }
    */

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue) { (deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Encountered error: \(error!)")
            }
            if deviceMotion != nil {
                self.grav_x = (deviceMotion?.gravity.x)!
                self.grav_y = (deviceMotion?.gravity.y)!
                self.grav_z = (deviceMotion?.gravity.z)!
                self.gravityStr = String(format: "grav_x: %.2f, grav_y: %.2f, grav_z: %.2f" ,
                                         self.grav_x,
                                         self.grav_y,
                                         self.grav_z)

                if self.prev_grav_z == 0.0 {
                    self.prev_grav_z = self.grav_z
                    self.sendOrNot = true
                }
                else{
                    if (self.grav_z - self.prev_grav_z) <= -0.25{
                        //print("Gravity: ",self.grav_z, self.prev_grav_z)
                        self.sendOrNot = true
                    }
                    else{
                        self.sendOrNot = false
                    }
                    self.prev_grav_z = self.grav_z
                }
               //self.sendData(x: self.gravityStr)
              // print(self.gravityStr)

                self.acc_x = (deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.x)!
                self.acc_y = (deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.y)!
                self.acc_z = (deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.z)!
                self.userAccelerStr = String(format: "acc_x: %.2f, acc_y: %.2f, acc_z: %.2f" ,
                                             self.acc_x,
                                             self.acc_y,
                                             self.acc_z)

                if (self.acc_z - self.prev_acc_z) <= -0.2{
                    //print("Accelero_z: ",self.acc_z, self.prev_acc_z)
                    self.sendOrNot = true
                }
                else{
                    self.sendOrNot = false
                }
                self.prev_acc_z = self.acc_z

                self.rotationRateStr = String(format: "rota_x: %.2f, rota_y: %.2f, rota_z: %.2f" ,
                                              (deviceMotion?.rotationRate.x)!,
                                              (deviceMotion?.rotationRate.y)!,
                                              (deviceMotion?.rotationRate.z)!)

               //self.sendData(x: self.rotationRateStr)

               //print(self.rotationRateStr)


                self.attitudeStr = String(format: "atti_roll: %.1f, atti_pitch: %.1f, atti_yaw: %.1f" ,
                                          (deviceMotion?.attitude.roll)!,
                                          (deviceMotion?.attitude.pitch)!,
                                          (deviceMotion?.attitude.yaw)!)

               //self.sendData(x: self.attitudeStr)

                //print(self.attitudeStr)

                //self.movement = self.gravityStr + self.userAccelerStr + self.rotationRateStr + self.attitudeStr
                if self.sendOrNot{
                    //print("Falling motion detected!")
                    self.movement = "\(self.gravityStr), \(self.userAccelerStr), \(self.rotationRateStr), \(self.attitudeStr), \("_1")"
                }
                else{
                    self.movement = "\(self.gravityStr), \(self.userAccelerStr), \(self.rotationRateStr), \(self.attitudeStr), \("_0")"
                }
                //print(self.movement)
                self.sendOrNot = false
            }
        }
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
        motionManager.stopDeviceMotionUpdates()
    }

    /**
    func sendData(x:String){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://147.46.242.219/addgyro2.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(x)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }

        task.resume()

    }

*/
   /**
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL
    {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

    func getFileUrl() -> URL
    {
        let filePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(filename!)
        return filePath
    }

    func startRecording(){
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do{
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileUrl(),
                                                settings: settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
            audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 5.0)

        }
        catch {
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }

        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            audioRecorder.record()
        } catch {
        }
    }

    func finishRecording(success: Bool) {
        audioRecorder.stop()
        audioRecorder = nil

        if success {
            print(success)
        } else {
            audioRecorder = nil
            print("Somthing Wrong.")
        }
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if !flag {
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
*/

    // generate a short unique id
    struct ShortCodeGenerator {

        private static let base62chars = [Character]("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        private static let maxBase : UInt32 = 62

        static func getCode(withBase base: UInt32 = maxBase, length: Int) -> String {
            var code = ""
            for _ in 0..<length {
                let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(min(base, maxBase)))
                code.append(base62chars[random])
            }
            return code
        }
    }


    // Getting the address from longitude and latitude
    func getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: String, withLongitude pdblLongitude: String) {
        var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        let lat: Double = Double("\(pdblLatitude)")!
        //21.228124
        let lon: Double = Double("\(pdblLongitude)")!
        //72.833770
        let ceo: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
        center.latitude = lat
        center.longitude = lon

        let loc: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude:center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)


        ceo.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc, completionHandler:
            {(placemarks, error) in
                if (error != nil)
                {
                    //print("reverse geodcode fail: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
                let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

                if pm.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]
                    //print(pm.country)
                    //print(pm.locality)
                    //print(pm.subLocality)
                    //print(pm.thoroughfare)
                    //print(pm.postalCode)
                    //print(pm.subThoroughfare)
                    var addressString : String = ""
                    if pm.subLocality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.subLocality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.thoroughfare != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.thoroughfare! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.locality! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.country != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.country! + ", "
                    }
                    if pm.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + pm.postalCode! + " "
                    }


                    //print(addressString)
                }
        })

    }


    @IBAction func manualBtnPressed() {
        // manual reporting functionality
        // generating 6 character long unique id

        let uniqueId = ShortCodeGenerator.getCode(length: 6)
        let txtMsg = "I am student \(uniqueId). I need help!"
        print(txtMsg)


        // Getting the address

        if manualLat != 0.0 && manualLong != 0.0 {
        var latStr = String(format:"%.2f",manualLat)
        var longStr = String(format:"%.2f",manualLong)
        getAddressFromLatLon(pdblLatitude: latStr, withLongitude: longStr)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://147.46.242.219/addmanual.php")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(manualLat)&b=\(manualLong)&c=\(txtMsg)"
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)



        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                //print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            //print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            //print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }

        task.resume()
        }

    }




    // when button clicked label is shown
    @IBAction func btnPressed() {

        if(!isRecording){
            let stopTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Stop Recording")
            stopTitle.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, stopTitle.length))
            button.setAttributedTitle(stopTitle)
            isRecording = true
            startWorkout() //Start workout session/healthkit streaming
        }else{
            let exitTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Start Recording")
            exitTitle.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], range: NSMakeRange(0, exitTitle.length))
            button.setAttributedTitle(exitTitle)
            isRecording = false
            healthStore.end(session!)

        }

    }

}

extension InterfaceController: HKWorkoutSessionDelegate{
    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {
        switch toState {
        case .running:
            //print(date)
            if let query = heartRateQuery(date){
                self.currentQuery = query
                healthStore.execute(query)
            }
        //Execute Query
        case .ended:
            //Stop Query
            healthStore.stop(self.currentQuery!)
            session = nil
        default:
            print("Unexpected state: \(toState)")
        }
    }

    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        //Do Nothing
    }

    func startWorkout(){
        // If a workout has already been started, do nothing.
        if (session != nil) {
            return
        }
        // Configure the workout session.
        let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
        workoutConfiguration.activityType = .running
        workoutConfiguration.locationType = .outdoor

        do {
            session = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
            session?.delegate = self
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to create workout session")
        }

        healthStore.start(self.session!)
        //print("Start Workout Session")


      // Here audio?
    /**
        if audioRecorder == nil {
            print("Pressed")
            filename = NSUUID().uuidString+".wav"
            self.startRecording()


        } else {
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            print("Filename\(filename!)")
            let pathPart = url.appendingPathComponent(filename!)
            let filePath = pathPart.path

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://147.46.242.219/addsound.php")! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let audioData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
            print("Result is\(getFileUrl().path)")
            print("Binary data printing")
            print(audioData)
            let postString = "a=\(audioData)"


            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
                print("response = \(response)")

                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")


            }
            task.resume()

            print("Pressed2")
            self.finishRecording(success: true)

        }

 */


    }

    func heartRateQuery(_ startDate: Date) -> HKQuery? {
        let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: nil, options: .strictEndDate)
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[datePredicate])

        let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: hrType, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
            //Do nothing
        }

        heartRateQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
            guard let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let sample = samples.first else { return }

                // after extraction of bpm value conversion to double
                let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))

                //print("Type of value is +\(type(of:value))")

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://147.46.242.219/addall.php")! as URL)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                //print(self.movement)
                //let randomStr = 42.0
                let postString = "gps_x=\(self.manualLat)&gps_y=\(self.manualLong)&a=\(self.movement)&hr=\(value)"
                //print(postString)
                request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                    data, response, error in

                    if error != nil {
                        //print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    //print("response = \(response)")

                    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                    //print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                }

                task.resume()

                //print("This line is executed!")
                //print(String(UInt16(value)))
            }

        }

        return heartRateQuery
    }


}

class HealthDataService {
    internal let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

    init() {}

    func authorizeHealthKitAccess(_ completion: ((_ success:Bool, _ error:Error?) -> Void)!) {
        let typesToShare = Set([hrType])
        let typesToSave = Set([hrType])
        healthKitStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesToShare, read: typesToSave) { (success, error) in
            completion(success, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I tried running your project in Xcode on Apple Watch, it crashed and the console said `Could not cast value of type 'BullyingDetection_WatchKit_Extension.LocationOutside' (0x92ca0) to 'CLLocationManagerDelegate' (0x6b433f84).`

On line 20 of your `LocationOutside` class, `locationManager.delegate = (self as! CLLocationManagerDelegate)` will have to be `locationManager.delegate = self` and the class will need to conform to the `CLLocationManagerManagerDelegate` protocol which also requires inheriting from `NSObject`:

```
class LocationOutside: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

}
```

This should lead you in the right direction.

It may help to also read about delegation here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID276.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I could fix that issue already. But, there is a slight issue with the authorization prompt both for the localization (GPS) functionality and the heartrate detection functionality (here the prompt comes with a big delay). Can you test it and tell me what is wrong? My intention was it to separate every functionality and utilize it in the InterfaceController. Can you test both of the functionalities and tell me what is wrong with them? because the code seems appropriate. Thank you very much. xcode project: https://file.io/OMZLyS

Comment: Here is a correct link: https://ufile.io/ebot2mri
The other one has a 404 error.